# overload vs default parameters in c++ standard

Tags: c++, overloading, std

I was reading another question, and it got me thinking. Often the standard specifies functions which have default parameters in their descriptions. Does the standard allow writing these as overloads instead?

For example, the standard says that `std::basic_string::copy` has the following declaration:

```
size_type copy(Ch* p, size_type n, size_type pos = 0) const;
```

Could a conforming implementation of the standard library implement this instead as two functions like this?

```
size_type copy(Ch* p, size_type n, size_type pos) const;
size_type copy(Ch* p, size_type n) const;
```

In this example, the second version could skip the `if(pos > size()) { throw out_of_range(); }` test that is necessary in the first one. A micro-optimization, but still you see the point of the example.

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler be (theoretically) capable of making that same optimization though, in the case of a default parameter?

Comment: @Harper Shelby, perhaps, perhaps not. It was just an example. My question is really about whether or not it is allowed for a writer of the standard library to do this.

Comment: @HarperShelby: Only if the function call is inlined.

Comment: @Evan Teran: I think it's an excellent question. My gut instinct is "No, the standard specifies the declaration, so you've got to do it that way", but my brief sojourn on comp.lang.c++.moderated a few years ago showed me just how little I really know of the standard. Obviously, there might very well exist more complicated scenarios where a programmer could put in some sort of improvement that would be difficult for a compiler to determine.

Comment: @Evan Teran: I was wondering if it could actually generate worse code because of the duplication. Also, it could perhaps trick the compiler to more aggressively inlining (since the second is shorter)... there might actually be more effects to those changes that one think of at first.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I don't think it'll generate **worse** code. I know at the very least gcc implements partial function inlining to address code duplication issue. I suspect that other compilers have similar clever optimizations.

Comment: @Evan Teran: LLVM has a function combination routine: http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mergefunc but it does not seem to address this. Also I don't think that partial inlining is for merging functions, it's more to extract a test at the call side and potentially avoid the call overhead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Could a conforming implementation of the standard library implement this instead as two functions like this?

Yes.  The C++ Standard (C++03 17.4.4.4/2-3) says:

> An implementation can declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a [Standard Library] class:
>
> -- by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature; the same latitude does not extend to the implementation of virtual or global or non-member functions, however.
>
> -- **by replacing a member function signature with default values by two or more member function signatures with equivalent behavior;**
>
> -- by adding a member function signature for a member function name.
>
> A call to a member function signature described in the C + + Standard library behaves the same as if the implementation declares no additional member function signatures

Comment: I think this applies only to the STL, not to user defined code. It would potentially break code similar to this: `struct base { virtual void foo( int i = 0 ); }; struct derived : base { void foo(); }; struct rederived : derived { void foo(); };` By implementing the default value as two different functions, both would have to be marked as virtual, and when calling `foo()` on an object of type `rederived` through a reference to `derived` it would call the final overrider (`rederived::foo()`) instead of the expected `derived::foo()`.

Comment: @David:  Yes, it only applies to Standard Library member functions (which is what the first sentence of the quoted Standardese says).  I thought the question was exclusively about the C++ Standard Library classes and member functions; I may have misunderstood it.

Comment: :) It seems as if I have been the one that did not read the question properly.