# Large binary file copy with standard C++

Tags: c++, file, stream, binary, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy a file in an sane, safe and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way)

I've searched for similar topics, but I couldn't find the answer for large binary files. Considering that I have very large binary files (like ~10 or ~100 GB each), how do I copy them with the following function, using standard C++ (no POSIX functions) :

```
bool copy(const std::string& oldName, const std::string& newName)
{
    /* SOMETHING */
}
```

EDIT :
Is the following implementation ok ? (adapted from the link in comments)

```
bool copy(const std::string& oldName, const std::string& newName)
{
    bool ok = false;
    std::ifstream oldStream(oldName.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream newStream(newName.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    if (oldStream.is_open() && newStream.is_open()) {
        newStream << oldStream.rdbuf();
        ok = (oldStream.good() && newStream.good());
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: Copy files means using the File System. Thus the **most efficient way** is to call the appropriate OS routines that interact with he File System.

Comment: is the operator '<<' ok for binary files ?

Comment: @Vincent, it should be when you're using `std::ios::binary`.  Unfortunately, it's also very slow on many implementations.

Comment: @Vincent: If you mean is a file opened in std::ios::binary mode. Then yes. The mode it is opened in has little affect on its usage see(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766636/difference-in-using-read-write-when-stream-is-opened-with-without-iosbinary-mo/12766972#comment17265240_12766972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `std::fopen`, `std::fread`, `std::fwrite`, and `std::fclose`, all of which are part of the standard C++ library (`#include <cstdio>`, very portable) and won't mess up binary data as long as you don't use a `"t"` specifier to `fopen`.

It will even be reasonably quick if you pick an appropriate buffer size (say 1 mebibyte) that gets you into the realm of sequential I/O performance.