# Copying large binary files on Windows using STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to copy some binary source file to a target file. [This seems to be the most popular way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way).

Here it is in a simple test application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    string sourceFile(argv[1]);
    string targetFile(argv[2]);

    ifstream src(sourceFile);
    ofstream dst(targetFile);

    dst << src.rdbuf();

    return 0;
}
```

If I build and run this example in Visual Studio 2010, only the first 522 bytes of the file are copied. Why is this so? And how can I extend this example to ensure all bytes are copied?

Comment: What' sthe value of the 523rd byte? Add the `std::ios::binary` flag to the constructors.

Comment: Won't the rdbuf just buffer up some of the file?

Comment: If you know this is going to be running on Windows anyway, why not just use the built-in [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) function and be done with it?

Comment: Last byte was '18'. Adding the ios::binary flag solved the problem. Makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: @JerryCoffin this is taken from cross platform code. `CopyFile` seems to be the quickest solution if it were Windows only.

Comment: `std::ios::binary` is definitely not the default file mode. Windows treats a `CTRL-Z` in a text input stream as an EOF where your Mac obviously doesn't.