# Faster way to move file in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, filesystems, partition

I'm trying to move files on linux by using C++.
The Problem is, that the source file and the destination folder can be in different partitions. So I can't simply move the files.
Ok. I decided to copy the file and delete the old one.

```
//-----
bool copyFile(string source, string destination)
{
    bool retval = false;
    ifstream srcF (source.c_str(), fstream::binary);
    ofstream destF (destination.c_str(), fstream::trunc|fstream::binary);
    if(srcF.is_open() && destF.is_open()){
        destF << srcF.rdbuf(); //copy files binary stream
        retval = true;
    }
    srcF.close();
    destF.close();
    return retval;
}
//-----
```

Now my problem.
I realized, this method is very slow. It takes 47 seconds for 100MB.
Simply copy a file with the console command takes 2-3 seconds.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The following answer is your best bet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way

Answer (score 3):

Streams are known to be pretty slow. You can either use tools provided by operating system or you can use some portable wrapper.

I would recommend `boost::filesystem`, because it is planned to be added to STL (C++14 ?).

Documentation here: [boost::filesystem::copy_file()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_file).

Answer (score -1):

Using Linux - rename(old name, new name);

Comment: This will not work. You will get an error (Invalid cross-device link), if source and destination are on different partitions.