# c++ copy file for ios and android

Tags: android, c++, ios

I am familiar with objective-c to copy file using cocoatouch sdk.
But I hope add copy file function to my game (cocos2dx c++).

Is there a common way for ios and android to copy file using c++?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream  src("from.ogv", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream  dst("to.ogv",   std::ios::binary);

    dst << src.rdbuf();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way).

Of course in Android you need NDK for that.