# Qt - copy a file from one directory to another

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT, I am not able to find out how to copy a file from one directory to another? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything at least?

Comment: i tried with QFile::copy() method. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy-2) which provides a copy method.

```
QFile::copy("/path/file", "/path/copy-of-file");
```

Comment: I think you should also specify that it returns `false` on error. Something like: `if(!QFile::copy(...)) { ...handle error... }`. In some cases an error can be ignored, in others, the process has to stop!

Comment: Yes, I did receive an error while using QFile::copy to Move from one drive letter to another. It turned out, QFile:rename function worked for me

Comment: UI stops if copying takes too long.

Answer (score 20):

If destination file exist, `QFile::copy` will not work. The solution is to verify if destination file exist, then delete it:

```
if (QFile::exists("/path/copy-of-file"))
{
    QFile::remove("/path/copy-of-file");
}

QFile::copy("/path/file", "/path/copy-of-file");
```

Comment: Why not just QFile::remove unconditionally? That is easier to read and faster to run.

Answer (score -4):

The following code works in windows for specified reasons. This will set the path to specified drive and create the folder you created in Under UI Mode. Then copies the file from source to destination. Here the source is installation directory contained some files which are used for plotting curves. this file are not modified by users. They just use it.

**hence this works as copy from installation directory to specified folder**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString str5 = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString src = "."; QString setpath;
    QDir dir(src);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        return;
    }
    dir.cdUp();
    //dir.cdUp();
    setpath = "E://";
    dir.setPath(setpath);
    QString dst_path = str5 + QDir::separator() ;
    dir.mkpath(dst_path);
    dir.cd(dst_path);
    QString filename = "gnu.plt";
    QString filename2 = "Load curve.plt";
    QString filename3 = "tube temp.plt";
    QFile file(filename);
    QFile file1(filename2);
    QFile file2(filename3);
    file.copy(src+QDir::separator()+filename, setpath+QDir::separator()+str5+QDir::separator()+filename);
    file1.copy(src+QDir::separator()+filename2, setpath+QDir::separator()+str5+QDir::separator()+filename2);
    file2.copy(src+QDir::separator()+filename3, setpath+QDir::separator()+str5+QDir::separator()+filename3);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use `QDir::separator()` when you set the `setpath` variable to `"E://"`. It looks like you meant `"\\"` also. Also your answer is way specialized for what the OP was asking. You should have simplified. Finally, you don't need to create a `QFile` object to do the copy since there is a static function. But if you do create such a QFile, then you should use the copy with one filename: `file.copy(destination);`.