# sendfile64 only copy about 2GB

Tags: c++, c, linux, sendfile

I need to use sendfile64 to copy about 16GB of files. What I have achieved so far is

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  long long src;
  long long dest;
  struct stat64 stat_buf;
  off64_t offset = 0LL;
  long long rc;

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <source> <destination>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  src = open64(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (src == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open '%s': %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  fstat64(src, &stat_buf);

  dest = open64(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, stat_buf.st_mode);
  if (dest == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open '%s': %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

 /* copy file using sendfile */
 rc = sendfile64 (dest, src, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
 if (rc == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error from sendfile: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
 }
 if (rc != stat_buf.st_size) {
   fprintf(stderr, "incomplete transfer from sendfile: %lld of %lld bytes\n",
           rc,
           (long long)stat_buf.st_size);
   exit(1);
 }

 /* clean up and exit */
 close(dest);
 close(src);

 return 0;
}
```

I have compiled using

```
g++ BigCopy2.cpp -o BigCopy2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DLARGEFILE64_SOURCE
```

The problem is I still can't copy more than 2GB of file.

Can someone point me where is my mistake?

Comment: Your casting of `stat_buf.st_size` in the `printf` call when the sizes doesn't match, seems to indicate that it's not a `long long` to begin with (even if it should be)? Could there be some problem there? Or is the cast because `stat_buf.st_size` is unsigned and you don't use an unsigned format code for `printf`?

Comment: You've spelled `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` wrong, but `g++` enables that by default anyway. Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit program? I assume 32-bit, because `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` are unnecessary on 64-bit

Comment: I'm using 64 bit ubuntu 13.10 and thanks for pointing my typo. But still even if I remove it, I can only copy 2GB. I didn't use it at first. It's just I'm so desperate here:)

Comment: If you're on 64-bit then `off_t` and `off64_t` are the same type, you should use the standard types and functions not the `xxx64` versions. If you're on 32-bit and you define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` then the same applies.

Comment: Does it always stop at the same position or does the amount of transferred bytes change with each run?

Answer (score 10):

You should use a loop to copy it all, sendfile() might, for various reasons, not copy all the data
with one call. As janneb points out, the return value of sendfile64 is a ssize_t, so we should not pass in more than SSIZE_MAX to sendfile, moreover the last argument to sendfile is a size_t which would be 32 bit on 32 bit platforms.

```
 /* copy file using sendfile */
while (offset < stat_buf.st_size) {
  size_t count;
  off64_t remaining = stat_buf.st_size- offset;
  if (remaining > SSIZE_MAX)
      count = SSIZE_MAX;
   else 
      count = remaining;
  rc = sendfile64 (dest, src, &offset, count);
  if (rc == 0) {
     break;
  }
  if (rc == -1) {
     fprintf(stderr, "error from sendfile: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     exit(1);
  }
}

 if (offset != stat_buf.st_size) {
   fprintf(stderr, "incomplete transfer from sendfile: %lld of %lld bytes\n",
           rc,
           (long long)stat_buf.st_size);
   exit(1);
 }
```

Note that you can replace all your 64 bit variants, off64_t, stat64, sendfile64, with off_t, stat, sendfile. As long as you have the `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag, that define will do the right thing and transform off_t to off64_t, sendfile to sendfile64 and so on if those types and functions are not already 64 bits (such as on 32 bit architectures).

Comment: Not only is the last argument of type size_t, but the return value is of type ssize_t, which has a smaller max value than size_t. So you need to transfer at most SSIZE_MAX bytes at a time in order to properly track how much each call actually transferred.

Comment: Yes, fair point - updated. At this point I'd rather use a normal, sane, easy to understand read()/write() loop.

Comment: Anyone tried this on MacOS? SendFile fails there and sendfile arguments are bit differently ordered so code will require bit of change. But in the end , Sendfile fails