# How can I copy a text file into another?

Tags: c++, file, stream

How can I copy a text file into another? I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    outfile << infile;

    return 0;
}
```

This just ends up leaving the following value in `output.txt`: `0x28fe78`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to read from the input file, then write into the output file

Comment: `<< infile` will just be writing out the internal file handle identifier. e.g. at the time you ran your code, the `input.txt` handle had id 0x28fe78

Comment: Try `outfile << infile.rdbuf();` instead.

Comment: Can you use an OS function to do this, like the Linux `cat` command?

Comment: This is a subset of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way

Comment: That line is actually invoking the implicit conversion to `void*`.  Before it was replaced with `basic_ios::operator bool()`in C++11, it returned `0` if `fail()` and otherwise some non-null pointer. So really it is implementation-defined what pointer is printed out. For example, in libstdc++ it returned `const_cast<basic_ios*>(this)` if `!fail()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the content of the input file in a string and print the string into the output file.
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    string content = "";
    int i;

    for(i=0; !infile.eof(); i++)     // get content of infile
        content += infile.get();
    infile.close();

    content.erase(content.end()-1);  //  last read character is invalid, erase it
    i--;

    cout << i << " characters read...\n";

    outfile << content;              // output
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```