# Write All But First N Lines of Stream Without Corrupting Destination Stream

Tags: c++, windows, newline

How can you write all but the first N lines of a stream without corrupting the destination stream?

For example, the following works fine when the source has n-1 or less lines and when source has n+1 or more lines, but sometimes fails when the source has exactly n lines:

```
void copy_all_but_first_n_lines(std::ifstream& source, std::ofstream& dest, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(source, line);
    }

    if (source.good()) dest << source.rdbuf();

    if (!dest.good()) throw std::runtime_error("destination turned bad after writing remainder of source");
}
```

With a source with exactly n lines, destination sometimes has the failbit set.

This failbit is only set when the source has a trailing newline.  I am testing this on Windows, and in a hex editor I see that files with a trailing newline and exactly n lines cause the destination stream to have the failbit set, but files with exactly n lines without a trailing end of line don't result in the failbit set.  All the files I'm testing with have newlines as "\r\n".

I tried opening the streams in both text and binary mode, but that didn't change the behavior.

---

If I change the code to use `std::copy` instead of writing the `rdbuf`, it works regardless of whether or not there is a trailing newline.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way/10195497), these two should be equivalent -- why is writing rdbuf failing while std::copy succeeds?

```
void copy_all_but_first_n_lines(std::ifstream& source, std::ofstream& dest, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(source, line);
    }

    if (source.good())
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(source);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> destination(dest);
        std::copy(begin, end, destination);
    }

    if (!dest.good()) throw std::runtime_error("destination turned bad after writing remainder of source");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the standard:

> ```
> basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);
> ```
>
> 7 *Effects:* Behaves as an unformatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.7, paragraph 1). After
>   the sentry object is constructed, if `sb` is null calls `setstate(badbit)` (which may throw `ios_base::failure`).
>   8 Gets characters from `sb` and inserts them in `*this`. Characters are read from `sb` and inserted until any of the following occurs:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs while getting a character from sb.
>
> 9 If the function inserts no characters, it calls `setstate(failbit)` (which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)). If an exception was thrown while extracting a character, the function sets `failbit` in error state, and if `failbit` is on in `exceptions()` the caught exception is rethrown.

So, they are only equivalent if at least one character will be copied.