# QFile::copy static function not copying file

Tags: c++, qt

I want to copy a text file with `QFile` with this code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QFile::copy("C:/p/text.txt", "C:/p/text1.txt");
}
```

I get no errors when I build it, but when I run the program, nothing happens.

Here's the complete source code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QfileDialog>
#include <QFile>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

int currentIndex = 0;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    currentIndex ++;
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    currentIndex --;
    if(currentIndex < 0)
    {
        currentIndex ++;
    }
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QFile::copy("C:/p/text.txt", "C:/p/text1.txt");
}
```

What could cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: "Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.", what do you have ? Also, "If a file with the same name already exists, copy() returns false". We need more information to help you.

Comment: Check that you have the permissions to modify C:\p and that the source file exists and you have permission to read.

Comment: it returns false. in the choosen directory, only the file i want to copy exists.

Comment: yes, i have all permissions i need.

Comment: What Qt and Windows version?

Comment: qt version is 5.3.2, windows version is 6.1.7601

Comment: @hardc0der Are you calling the function (just to make sure)?

Comment: I've noticed same problem and it seems that implementation of copy() is not good. It somehow think you have no enough permission to copy even if you do.

Comment: @Rinzler yes, of course.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic ok, and how can i get it to work?

Comment: @hardc0der Could you show the code?

Comment: Can you write in that dir from your code? Can you copy the file with other procedures in your code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way

Comment: @hardc0der Unfortunately i haven't found quality way to do it. I'll proposal a solution which works sometimes but is far from quality.

Comment: @hardc0der Please, close and reopen `QCreator` (I suppose).

Comment: @hardc0der Are you sure that `on_pushButton_4_clicked` is really the *slot/listener* for a button (click) in your application? Do you have 4 buttons in your application?

Comment: ok. thank you all for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed same problem and it seems that implementation of copy() is not good. It somehow think you have no enough permission to copy even if you do have. Some Windows permission conflict.

There is no good workaround but you might try to copy file by redoing whole process (it works sometimes):

1. Open source file for reading
2. Open (create) destination file for writing.
3. copy all data from first file to second one.

Far from perfect but sometimes it works.

Comment: well ok. but is there no better way?

Comment: Yes. Use windows native API CopyFile()

Comment: In, meanwhile, make sure that you DO have enough permissions which don't require elevation and that destination file doesn't exists.