# Is the implementation of QFile::copy(source, dest) in Qt is faulty sometimes?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString source = "E:/source/tty.txt";
QString dest = "E:/Destination";

bool status =QFile::copy(source,dest); // status = false
```

It doesn't copy the source file to destination file. Why?

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ? Imagine you write a bug report, do you think it will be taken serious if all you say is : "it doesnt work" ??

Comment: you should define your destination file name and format. `QString dest = "E:/Destination/tty.txt";`

Comment: Does file named "E:/Destination" exist?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions?

Comment: @tobi303 :edited the question.

Comment: @JLev: yes i do have the right permission

Comment: @olya : yes the destination folder exists

Comment: You can't debug this properly without building Qt yourself first. Once you do, you can enter the `QFile::copy` method in the debugger and see *why* it fails. Until you do so, and update the question with the results, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't define file name for destination directory.

Try this:

```
QString source = "E:/source/tty.txt";
QString dest = "E:/Destination/tty.txt";

bool status = QFile::copy(source,dest);
```

**More info**:
This is an overloaded function.
Copies the file fileName to newName. Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.

If a file with the name newName already exists, copy() returns false (i.e., QFile will not overwrite it).

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy

Comment: I just try it on my pc before post the answer. make sure your directory is correct.

Comment: it worked in previous programs, but it's not working in my current project. and i did checked my directory, it exists. Also i've found many links stating that QFile::copy sometimes doesn't work well in windows.

Comment: Clean your project (maybe remove build folder) and `run qmake+ rebuild  `project again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735545/qfilecopy-static-function-not-copying-file?rq=1 vist this link

Comment: Did you try above link solution ? try it plz

Comment: but that simply means Qfile::copy() function is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

By using a QFile instance and method `QFile::copy(const QString &newName)`, you could find out the error code by using `QFileDevice::error()` if copy returns false.

Something like this:

```
QFile source("E:/source/tty.txt");
QString dest = "E:/Destination/tty.txt";
if (!source.copy(dest))
{
     qDebug() << "File error" << source.error();  
}
```

Comment: I've tried this also. I think there is something wrong with copy function , something is happening inside copy function that stops it from copying to destination