# Could someone tell me why copying a file like this doesn't work?

Tags: c++, windows, file, copy

I am trying to copy an exe file byte by byte.  I compared the hex files of the 2 and they are quite different.  It seems like some values are not getting loaded in..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream fin("file.exe", ifstream::binary);
    vector<char> buffer(1, 0);


    ofstream newfile;
    newfile.open("newfile.exe", ios::binary);

    while (fin.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size())){
        streamsize s = fin.gcount();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++){
            if (buffer[i] != EOF){
                newfile << buffer[i];
                cout << buffer[i] << endl;
            } else {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the streamsize s = fin.gcount() statement? You don't use its result, anyway.

Comment: The vector is in case I want to start grabbing more than one byte at a time. I compare to EOF because that has worked so far.

Comment: The most obvious problem is `buffer[i] != EOF`. Since `buffer[i]` contains a character and `EOF` is not a character, this comparison makes no sense.

Comment: @Jlegend: Yet here you are complaining that it _doesn't_ work....

Comment: One issue is that the file stream is a *block* device, meaning it likes to transfer data in large blocks.  I suggest a minimum size of the vector to be 512 (a common sector size).

Answer (score 7):

Why do you read into and write out of a vector with a single `char`? What is the purpose of `s`? Why do you attempt to compare against `EOF` with IOStreams? This code appears to be a bizarre mixture of C and C++, with the result being entirely broken!

Here's how I'd do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin ("file.exe",    std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream fout("newfile.exe", std::ios::binary);

    std::copy(
       std::istream_iterator<char>(fin),
       std::istream_iterator<char>(),
       std::ostream_iterator<char>(fout)
    );
}
```

Or even just:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin ("file.exe",    std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream fout("newfile.exe", std::ios::binary);

    fout << fin.rdbuf();
}
```

No muss, no fuss!

This works really well for streams in the general case, but, [if all you want to do is perform a byte-for-byte file copy, you'd get your OS to do it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195497/560648). It can do it much faster than you can! For example, [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.

Comment: or even simpler : `newfile<<fin.rdbuff();` in one line.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yeah or that  :) (`rdbuf`)

Comment: I recommend the OP find an OS API for this.  The OS should have some optimized file copying functions already tested.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the help. This is how I ended up getting the job done.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>      
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream is("file.exe", ios::binary);
    ofstream fs("newfile.exe", ios::binary);
    if (is) {
        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, is.beg);

        char * buffer = new char[length];

        is.read(buffer, length);
        is.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            fs << buffer[i];
        }

        delete[] buffer;
    }
}
```