# Function to clone HDF5 file via C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, hdf5

Thank you in advance for your time.

I have a rather simple question regarding the best/easiest way to clone (I.e. Make a copy in disk) of an HDF5 file. For example, there is an HDF5 file: file.h5. I would like to copy the contents of this file into file_BU.h5. The reason for this is that there is a possibility my job that writes to the file will be killed partway through a write (to multiple datasets), and I would like to have a backup in between each "generation" of writes so I can recover the most recent good state.

Of course I could use normal file copy code such as [Copy a file in a sane, safe and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way) (or a naive system( "cp file.h5 file_BU.h5" ) ). However, this is an HDF5 specific question -- I'm wondering if there is a function to clone() an HDF5 file. Example code snippet below:

```
H5::H5File file;
file = H5::H5File( "file.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC );
//TODO Write datasets etc. to file
std::string file2name = "file_BU.h5";

//This is the thing I would like to do:
file.clone( file2name );
file.close();

//file_BU.h5 and file.h5 are now identical on disk...
```

Comment: What reasons are speaking against making a copy at the file-system level? The only advantage of parsing and re-formatting the file I can see is that to some degree, it verifies the integrity of the file. But it will also be slower and probably not easier.

Comment: Thanks for the good question. No reasons other than there might be an HDF5 library function to do it that will work from the H5::H5File, instead of having to know the string of the filename it's open from...

Comment: Why don't you read your file using `std::fstream` to an `std::string` as binary and then write it again to another file? Why does this have to be HDF5 specific at all? Are you willing to do this just for fun?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the whole doc, but closest to what You are looking for seems to be https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-Copy
, but You obviously need to write some function to copy the whole thing.
You can check the rest of available functions here https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5Front.html#LowLevelAPIs and I would also look at the source of `h5copy` command line tool.