# Copying a huge file using read(), write() and open() API's in linux

Tags: c, linux, api

I have been learning system programming in linux and I'm trying to copy a video using read() and write (). The problem I'm facing is that I cannot save the entire file into a buffer since its a huge file.

I thought I could loop it in since I was using write with append flag but then how would I use it with read?

This is my messed up code. I would appreciate any help:

```
int main() {

    int movie_rdfd = open("Suits.mp4", O_RDONLY); //fd for read
    off_t file_length = (int)(fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END));

    printf("This is fd for open: %d\n", movie_rdfd); //line to be deleted
    char* Save[fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END)];

    int C1 = read(movie_rdfd, Save, );

    printf("Result of Read (C1): %d\n", C1); //line to be deleted

    int movie_wrfd = open("Suits_Copy.mp4", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644); //fd for write

    printf("This is result of open: %d\n", movie_wrfd); //line to be deleted

    int C2 = write(movie_wrfd, Save, fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END));

    printf("Result of Read (C2): %d\n", C2); //line to be deleted

    close(movie_rdfd);
    close(movie_wrfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Also its showing segmentation fault when I try to find file size

Comment: I'd start adding `if (movie_rdfd == -1) { perror("Error opending file: "); return 1}` just after open call to check if the file was opened correctly.

Comment: Creating an array with non-const size compile time is non-standard as far as I know. Also I'm sure you don't want an array of pointers to chars. You want to read and write blocks and that's it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It is [VLAs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: @LPs Thanks, didn't know they were accepted in C, been away too much.

Comment: Using `mmap` with `PROT_READ` on `Suits.mp4` will ease your task significantly.

Comment: The buffer should be `char`, not `char*`. Allocate a sufficient size, then just `read` and note the number returned. Then `write` the same amount of bytes. Repeat until end of file.

Comment: I'm not sure why `mmap()` is so often put forth as a solution for uses such as this.  Read [this from one Linus Torvalds regarding `mmap()` - you may have heard of him.](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy a file in a sane, safe and efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way)

Comment: when using `open()` the code should also contain a call to `close()`

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements.

Comment: this line: `off_t file_length = (int)(fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END));` is not correct.:   1) the function `fseek()` returns an `int`, so no need to cast to `int`  2) the returned value is an `int`, so why try to force it into a `off_t` variable?

Comment: this line: `char* Save[fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END)];` is declaring a (VERY) large array of pointers to char.   What you really want is an array of char, not an array of pointers to char.  Note: a pointer to char is (with a 32 bit architecture) 4 bytes

Answer (score 4):

The proper logic for copying a file in POSIX.1 systems, including Linux, is roughly

```
Open source file
Open target file
Repeat:
    Read a chunk of data from source
    Write that chunk to target
Until no more data to read
Close source file
Close target file
```

Proper error handling adds a significant amount of code, but I consider it a necessity, not an optional thing to be added afterwards if one has the time to do so.

(I am so strict in this, that I'd fail anyone who omits error checking, even if their program otherwise functioned properly. The reason is basic sanity: A tool that may blow up in your hands is not a tool, it is a bomb. There are enough bombs in the software world already, and we don't need more "programmers" who create those. What we need are reliable tools.)

Here is an example implementation with proper error checking:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define  DEFAULT_CHUNK  262144  /* 256k */

int copy_file(const char *target, const char *source, const size_t chunk)
{
    const size_t size = (chunk > 0) ? chunk : DEFAULT_CHUNK;
    char        *data, *ptr, *end;
    ssize_t      bytes;
    int          ifd, ofd, err;

    /* NULL and empty file names are invalid. */
    if (!target || !*target || !source || !*source)
        return EINVAL;

    ifd = open(source, O_RDONLY);
    if (ifd == -1)
        return errno;

    /* Create output file; fail if it exists (O_EXCL): */
    ofd = open(target, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    if (ofd == -1) {
        err = errno;
        close(ifd);
        return err;
    }

    /* Allocate temporary data buffer. */
    data = malloc(size);
    if (!data) {
        close(ifd);
        close(ofd);
        /* Remove output file. */
        unlink(target);
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    /* Copy loop. */
    while (1) {

        /* Read a new chunk. */
        bytes = read(ifd, data, size);
        if (bytes < 0) {
            if (bytes == -1)
                err = errno;
            else
                err = EIO;
            free(data);
            close(ifd);
            close(ofd);
            unlink(target);
            return err;
        } else
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;

        /* Write that same chunk. */
        ptr = data;
        end = data + bytes;
        while (ptr < end) {

            bytes = write(ofd, ptr, (size_t)(end - ptr));
            if (bytes <= 0) {
                if (bytes == -1)
                    err = errno;
                else
                    err = EIO;
                free(data);
                close(ifd);
                close(ofd);
                unlink(target);
                return err;
            } else
                ptr += bytes;
        }
    }

    free(data);

    err = 0;
    if (close(ifd))
        err = EIO;
    if (close(ofd))
        err = EIO;
    if (err) {
        unlink(target);
        return err;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function takes the target file name (to be created), source file name (to be read from), and optionally the preferred chunk size. If you supply 0, the default chunk size is used. On current Linux hardware, 256k chunk size should reach maximum throughput; smaller chunk size may lead to slower copy operation on some (big and fast) systems.

The chunk size should be a power of two, or a small multiple of a large power of two. Because the chunk size is chosen by the caller, it is dynamically allocated using [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)/[`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html). Note that it is explicitly freed in error cases.

Because the target file is always created -- the function will fail, returning `EEXIST` if the target file already exists --, it is removed ("unlinked") if an error occurs, so that no partial file is left over in error cases. (It is a common bug to forget to free dynamically allocated data in the error path; this is often called "leaking memory".)

The exact usage for [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), and [`unlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) can be found at the [Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html).

`write()` returns the number of bytes written, or -1 if an error occurs. (Note that I explicitly treat 0 and all negative values smaller than -1 as I/O errors, because they should not normally occur.)

`read()` returns the number of bytes read, -1 if an error occurs, or 0 if there is no more data.

Both `read()` and `write()` may return a *short count*; i.e., less than was requested. (In Linux, this does not happen for normal files on most local filesystems, but only an idiot relies on the above function to be used on such files. Handling short counts isn't that complex, as you can see from the above code.)

If you wanted to add a progress meter, for example using a *callback function*, for example

```
void progress(const char *target, const char *source,
              const off_t completed, const off_t total);
```

then it would make sense to add an [`fstat(ifd, &info)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) call before the loop (with `struct stat info;` and `off_t copied;`, the latter counting the number of bytes copied). That call too may fail or report `info.st_size == 0`, if the source is e.g. a named pipe instead of a normal file. This means that the `total` parameter might be zero, in which case the progress meter would display only the progress in bytes (`completed`), with the remaining amount unknown.

Comment: Linux does have a maximum IO size that, when exceeded, will result in a partial `read()`/`write()` even on regular files on any file system.  IIRC, it's just a bit short of 2 GB, but I can't find a reference right now.  So if you try to `write()` a 4GB buffer, the call will return something just short of 2GB.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I know, it's one page short of 2**32 bytes in all Linux architectures. I filed a bug (814296), a duplicate of RHSA-2012:0862, at the Red Hat Bugzilla in 2012, and the limit (kernel `MAX_RW_COUNT` defined in `include/linux/fs.h`) was added to the VFS layer in the Linux kernel `fs/read_write.c:vfs_write()` due to bugs like that.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: the code can be shortened a bit if you isolate the error recovery calls (free, close, close, unlink, return) at the end of the function and put cascading goto labels in front of each operation.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Similar to error handling in the Linux kernel, yes. In this particular case, I think it is better to keep all the cleanup with the error checking code, for ease of understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some critiques, and then how I'd do it:

This is good:

```
int movie_rdfd = open("Suits.mp4", O_RDONLY); //fd for read
```

This is, ummm, not so good:

```
off_t file_length = (int)(fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END));
```

`fseek()` is for `stdio`-based `FILE *` pointers opened with `fopen()`, not `int` file descriptors from `open`.  To get the size of a file opened with `open()`, [use `fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html):

```
struct stat sb;
int rc = fstat( movie_rdfd, &sb );
```

Now you know how big the file is.  But if it's a really big file, it's not going to fit into memory, so this is bad:

```
char* Save[fseek(movie_rdfd, 0, SEEK_END)];
```

That's bad in multiple ways, too - it should be `char Save[]`, not `char *`.  But either way, for a really large file, it's not going to work - it's too big to put on the stack as a local variable.

And you don't want to read the whole thing at once, anyway - it likely won't work as you'll likely get a partial read.  [Per the read standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> The `read()` function **shall attempt to read** `nbyte` bytes from the
>   file associated with the open file descriptor ...
>
> ***RETURN VALUE***
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read. ...

Note that it says "shall attempt to read" and it returns "the number of bytes actually read".  So you have to handle partial reads with a loop anyway.

Here's one really simple way to copy a file using `open()`, `read()`, and `write()` (note that it really should have some more error checking - for example, the `write()` results should be checked to be sure they match the number of bytes read):

```
#define BUFSIZE ( 32UL * 1024UL )

char buffer[ BUFSIZE ];
int in = open( nameOfInputFile, O_RDONLY );
int out = open( nameOfOutputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );

// break loop explicitly when read fails or hits EOF
for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = read( in, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    if ( bytesRead <= 0 )
    {
        break;
    }

    write( out, buffer, bytesRead );
}
```

Note that you don't even need to know how big the file is.

There are a lot of things you can do to make this a bit faster - they're usually not worth it as the above code will likely run at about 90% of maximum IO rate on most systems.

Comment: This is not entirely safe because `read(2)` can fail in non-EOF cases, too. Also, the result of `write` must be checked, too.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev *This is not entirely safe because `read(2)` can fail in non-EOF cases, too.*  And when `read()` fails in non-EOF cases, what does it return?

Comment: It still returns -1, but then, you have not correctly copied the file. Common non-EOF errors are `EINTR` and `EISDIR` (the file gets opened, but if it's a directory it fails on the first read).

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev It's not meant to be a complete solution. I'd rather have the questioner learn something by doing it himself.