# C++: How can I optimize copying the rest of a .txt file?

Tags: c++, optimization, text, ifstream, ofstream

I have large text files that I need to embed a code (time) into, part of the way through the file. I do this by iterating through an ***ifstream*** to the point the code needs to be inserted into, and then proceed to iterate through the rest of the file, continuously copying the data into a new ***ofstream*** file.

These files are large, and almost all of this simple copy and paste operation occurs after the code insertion. This takes a while to execute. **I was wondering if there was a way to optimize copying the rest of the file in bulk** (rather than word-by-word iteration for the rest of the file). This is the relevant code segment:

```
while (!in.eof())
{
    in >> value;
    if ((counter > 392) && (counter < 399) && (timePosition < 6))
    {
        rounded = floorf(value * 1000) / 1000;
        value = rounded + (time[timePosition] * .00001);
        timePosition++;
    }
    out << value << " ";
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: If you're using Linux, the `split` command could be a lot more efficient.  I.e., split the file in two, write your new lines, then concatenate them all back together again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Check the return value of >>

Comment: [Copy a file in a sane, safe and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way)

Comment: @JeffUK That sounds useful - is there a good example of split in code? (there will be a Linux version and a Windows version, but the Linux one needs to be the fast one)

Comment: `out << in.rdbuf();`.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom Kenny, you lost me there. Could you explain?

Comment: Do these files fit into memory? Then you could read the whole file into a std::string, parse to the right location, then write out the first part, then the inserted part, and finally the last part back to the output file.

Comment: @Pete Becker - Could you invoke that .rdbuf() at the completion of inserting the time code (which would copy the rest of the text file from that point in the ifstream)?

Comment: @J.R. They are about 11MB. Would the string parsing be a faster route? How would this be expressed in code?

Comment: 11 MB sounds OK; can't say for sure if it is faster; you could try. To read the string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: @Deduplicator that's a great link, but it really only covers the case where you want to copy the entire file, not just a part of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom As others commented, one can adapt most of the given solutions appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete Becker's answer above was just what was needed.

```
out << in.rdbuf();
```

What used to execute in a minute now takes seconds using this buffer-pointer command. The new code:

```
while (counter < 399)
{
  in >> value;
  if ((counter > 392) && (counter < 399) && (timePosition < 6))
  {
    rounded = floorf(value * 1000) / 1000;
    value = rounded + (time[timePosition] * .00001);
    timePosition++;
  }
  out << value << " ";
  counter++;
}
out << in.rdbuf();
```

Thank you to all of you who commented; you were very informative, and I now know a lot more than I did when I asked this question!

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would copy the whole file, just a small portion of it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom From what I've tested so far, it seems to have worked; it transfers the rest of the file extremely quickly after the code insertion loop (the [out << in.rdbuf();] at the end)

Comment: I've been reading up on `rdbuf` and it does appear to have the ability to stream the entire contents of the file, but it would require `operator<<` to be specialized to handle it properly. Evidently it has, which is a nice surprise.

Comment: As an improvement, consider reading the first 399+ bytes into a buffer at once, replace parts as you want, and write it at once. Should be much faster.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's the case; I'm just not sure how to express that extra bit of efficiency via code. How would one bring those bytes into a buffer, and access the specific bytes for modification? (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: Use [`std::istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`std::ostream::write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), and an automatic char-array.