# TOCTTOU - Using access before handling file

Tags: c++, file-handling, coverity, tocttou

I have this function that copies files to a mirror directory and then deletes the old one. It works well however, in Coverity, my code shows up as a TOCTTOU warning.

```
void function(){
    const char *original_key = "path/to/file/filename";
    const char *mirror_key = "path/to/another/file/filename";

    if((access(original_key, F_OK) == 0) && (access(mirror_key, F_OK) == 0)){
        copy_file("/bin/cp %s %s", original_key, mirror_key); /*copy function in another cpp file*/
        unlink(original_key);
    }
}

/* in another cpp file */
int copy_file(const char*command, ...){
    int rc = -1;
    va_list args;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    va_start(args, command);
    vasprintf(&buffer, command, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (buffer)
    {
        char *wrd;
        char *ptr = buffer;
        std::vector<const char *> list;
        while ((wrd = strsep(&ptr, " ")) != NULL)
        {
            if (strlen(wrd))
            {
                list.push_back(wrd);
            }
        }
        if (list.size() > 0)
        {
            char *argv[list.size() + 1];
            for (size_t idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx++)
            {
                argv[idx] = (char *)list[idx];
            }
            argv[list.size()] = NULL;
            rc = system_spawn_args(argv);
        }
        free(buffer);
    }
    return(rc);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent TOCTTOU in this situation?

note: move did not work - Cross Device Error.

Thanks

Comment: There is a lot of code missing. So, very difficult to judge. I guess that in reality "original_key" and "mirror_key" have a different content. Also, "access" checks the file and not the path. And, how do you copy? How do you open the mirror file?. I think, this essetial information is missing. BTW. I have encountered only very very few false positives from Coverity. Compared to QAC or SonarCube or Lint, it is really reliable (my personal experience . . .)

Comment: This is very much application dependent. How much of a problem is it if the original file is not deleted?

Comment: @Armin Montigny - added the missing pieces based on your question. I hope this helps

Comment: @user1937198 - i need to actually delete it

Comment: @JezT is it a problem if the file is lost in transit? If so you could open the file, delete it, and then copy the contents to a new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my main function was basically to move one file to another. I just used rename() this did the job and also did not warn me as a TOCTTOU in Coverity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is maybe a typical Unix / Linux bug using the function access. The exact details, even with an example, are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). There are also recomendations on how to mitigate the risk.

Since it is described very well in the linked Wikepedia article, I will not repeat it here.

And, because there is no C++ code in your example, you may want to rewrite the code in C++. Also your "copy-function" using a system call, seems to be overly complex.

Please consider to refactor it. Therefor I would also recomend to you to read an article about copying a file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way) on stackoverflow.

If your code is non productive and for home use only, then you can also ignore this message.